# Django Q Error: could not translate host name "db" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution

Tags: python-3.x, django, docker, django-q

This is the **docker compose** production configuration that I have created:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:  
  db:
    image: postgres:12.8-alpine
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    env_file:
      - ./.env.prod.db
    ports:
      - 5400:5432    

  redis:
     image: redis:alpine
     ports:
         - 6379:6379

  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/ps_survey
      - static_volume:/ps_survey/staticfiles
    env_file:
      - ./.env.prod
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - db

  django-q:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py qcluster
    volumes:
      - .:/ps_survey
    env_file:
      - ./.env.prod
    depends_on:
      - redis

  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/ps_survey/staticfiles
    ports:
      - 86:80
    depends_on:
      - web

volumes:
  postgres_data:
  static_volume:
```

Dockerfile configuration:

```bash
FROM python:3
WORKDIR ./ps_survey
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY ./req2.txt .
RUN pip install -r req2.txt
COPY . .
CMD gunicorn ps_survey.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
```

.env.prod configurations:

```
DEBUG=0
SECRET_KEY='******************************'
DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS=["*"]
DB_NAME=*********
DB_USER=*********
DB_PASSWORD=********
DB_HOST='db'
DB_PORT=5432
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD=**********
EMAIL_HOST_USER=**********
EMAIL=*************
PASSWORD=**********
BACKGROUND=True
```

.env.prod.db configurations

```
POSTGRES_USER=*******
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=******
POSTGRES_DB=*******
```

Error that I am getting :

```
django-q_1  | 16:00:19 [Q] ERROR could not translate host name "db" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

Because of which, the task is not running

Comment: Does the `django-q` container need to `depends_on: [db]`?  Is the database container actually starting up?

Comment: @DavidMaze Do you mean to say that I add 'depends_on : db' part under django_q service? Because when I check with 'docker ps -a', db container is up and running.

Comment: With the setup you currently have, it's possible the `django-q` container starts up before the `db` container exists, and you'd get this error.  (Note that `depends_on:` still has a possible case where the `db` container exists but isn't ready to accept connections yet.)